# ng-if indexOf with JSON Arrays

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON Output of `items` - To display a single item i use `ng-repeat="item in items"`. And I can access the currently logged in user object with `user`

Each item can belong to multiple wishlists of users. If a user adds an item to his wishlist the `user_id` gets saved within `item.wishlists`

The JSON Output of a single `item` looks simplified something like this:

```
{"id":1,"title":"This is a tile","wishlists":[{"user_id":2},{"user_id":3}]}
```

when i do `user.id` i get the ID of the current logged in user.

Now I want to use `ng-if` within the `ng-repeat="item in items"` to check if the current_user has already added this item to his wishlist, and then to display this user an "remove from wishlist" button instead of "add to wishlist".

**My not working approach is:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
  <a href="" ng-click="addToWishlist(item)" ng-if="item.wishlists.indexOf(user.id) == -1">Wish</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="removeFromWishlist(item)" ng-if="item.wishlists.indexOf(user.id) > -1">Undo-Wish</a>
</div>
```

**Can I use indexOf like this? Or what would be the correct angularJS way to check if user.id is within item.wishlists user_id's?**

> **Update:**

**View:** (ctrl.hasWished changes the icon from 'favorite' if true to 'favorite_border' if false)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <md-button class="md-icon-button feed-wish md-warn" aria-label="Wish" ng-click="ctrl.toggleWish(item)">
        <i class="material-icons">favorite{{ctrl.hasWished(item) ? '' : '_border' }}</i>
      </md-button> 
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
  // Check if User has wished this item already: Should return true or false
  this.hasWished = function(item) {
    return item.wishlists.some(function(wishlist) {
      return wishlist.user_id === Auth._currentUser.id; // returns true if currently logged in user id is on wishlist
    });
  };

  this.toggleWish = function(item) {
    if (!this.hasWished) {
      this.hasWished = true;
      items.wish(item); // sends PUT request
      ToastService.show(item.product + ' added to Wish List');
    } else {
      this.hasWished = false;
      items.unWish(item); // sends DELETE request
      ToastService.show(item.product + ' removed from Wish List');
    }
  }
```

When I click on the button if its false before, it sends the PUT request, and I also get the ToastService message "added..", if I click again it sends the DELETE request and the ToastService message "removed..". But the Icon doesn't change from "favorite" to "favorite_border". When I reload the page the right Icons are displayed.

I also have this error message within the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/auctions/auctionCtrl-f2cb59b8ad51e03a2264ef2c6e759a54.js?body=1:33:52
    at Array.some (native)
    at hasWished (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/auctions/auctionCtrl-f2cb59b8ad51e03a2264ef2c6e759a54.js?body=1:32:30)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:13323:15), <anonymous>:4:318)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch [as get] (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:14303:31)
    at Scope.$digest (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:15819:40)
    at Scope.$apply (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:16098:24)
    at done (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:10547:47)
    at completeRequest (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:10745:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:10686:9)
```

and when clicking also this error:

```
TypeError: v2.hasWished is not a function
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:13323:15), <anonymous>:4:318)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch [as get] (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:14303:31)
    at Scope.$digest (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:15819:40)
    at Scope.$apply (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:16098:24)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular-touch/angular-touch-b4d02ed602708a1c93b51087222e0363.js?body=1:478:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://ruby-on-rails-140223.nitrousapp.com:3000/assets/angular/angular-81b9b668c3f93c8ccb76b27ad984d9b6.js?body=1:3299:21)
```

Comment: try to use `(item.wishlists|filter:{user_id:user.id}).length==0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter should works:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
  <a href="" ng-click="addToWishlist(item)" ng-if="!(item.wishlists|filter:{user_id:user.id}).length">Wish</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="removeFromWishlist(item)" ng-if="(item.wishlists|filter:{user_id:user.id}).length">Undo-Wish</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i would avoid putting so much logic into the view, remember seperation of concerns, this code would be better on a function inside a controller

Comment: We have to add two `ng-repeat` blocks with same filters if we'll want to render wished/notWished user lists, and all will looks ok. It's not a logic. It just view options. But I agree, in any cases this will need in optimization. Then datasource will return bool mark for this in answer.

Comment: @RanSasportas yes, I think I will implement your the logic of your example within the controller later, for now its just a simple solution to build the remove function in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use indexOf function for this task.
instead i recommand you to create a function on the scope within the controller which checks if the wishlist contains the user in that manner -

```
function isUserOnWishlist(item) {
    return item.wishlists.some(function(wishlist) {
        return wishlist.user_id === user.id; // ( on $scope ? )
    });
}
```

on the view -

```
<a href="" ng-click="addToWishlist(item)" ng-if="!isUserOnWishlist(item.wishlists)">Wish</a>
<a href="" ng-click="addToWishlist(item)" ng-if="isUserOnWishlist(item.wishlists)">Undo-Wish</a>
```

the isUserOnWishlist function will iterate on each user on the wishlist and return true only if it will find atleast one wishlist which passes this - `wishlist.user_id === user.id`.
you could have used the indexOf function if the wishlist was a list of int's instead list of objects.

i recommend you check out the MDN js array functions documentation, you can find there explanation about all the cool array functions thats comes out of the box with js.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

good luck.

Comment: Hi, I am using this now it works, but if the wishlist is empty, i get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null at Array.some (native)` - how can i solve this?

Comment: Are you sure the user variable isn't null?

Comment: yes, I am using `return wishlist.user_id === Auth._currentUser.id` instead of user.id. (I will update my question to show you what I am doing alltogether right now)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use indexOf, check this post: 
"There is one final aspect to consider: equality. The indexOf method uses strict equality (===) to determine if an element matches your search. This works great for primitives like strings and numbers. But you may have difficulty using indexOf to search for a given object or array"
[finding-array-elements-with-array-indexof](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/finding-array-elements-with-array-indexof.html)

You can use $filter  [API Reference / ng / filter components in ng / filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), or maybe, you should create a function in your controller passing as a paremeters the current item and the user.id to do this or create a custom directive. Check this if you want an idea for your custom function: [how-to-find-index-of-an-item-in-javascript-object-array/](http://debugmode.net/2013/02/19/how-to-find-index-of-an-item-in-javascript-object-array/)

Regards